# collectionviewCell not change when transition to other collectionviewController

Tags: ios, ios7, uicollectionview

I create 2 UICollectionView classes, each one use 2 different UICollectionViewCell

```
@interface PhotosCollectionViewController : UICollectionViewController
@interface FullScreenCollectionViewController : UICollectionViewController

@interface PhotoCell : UICollectionViewCell
@interface FullPhotoCell : UICollectionViewCell<UIScrollViewDelegate>
```

In **PhotosCollectionViewController.m**, I register PhotoCell class and choose next view controller is FullScreenCollectionViewController when didSelect

```
//Register Cell
-(id)initWithCollectionViewLayout:(UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)layout{
    if (self = [super initWithCollectionViewLayout:layout])
    {        
        [self.collectionView registerClass:[PhotoCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:CELL_ID];
    }
    return self;
}
//dequence resuse code
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    PhotoCell* cell = (PhotoCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CELL_ID forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSLog(@"reuse CELL");
    FICDPhoto *photo = [_photos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.imageView.image = [photo sourceImage];
    return cell;
}
//Next ViewController transition code
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIViewController *vc = [self nextViewControllerAtPoint:CGPointZero];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}


-(UICollectionViewController*)nextViewControllerAtPoint:(CGPoint)p
{
    FullScreenCollectionViewController* nextCollectionViewController = [[FullScreenCollectionViewController alloc] initWithCollectionViewLayout:[[FullScreenFlowLayout alloc] init]];

    nextCollectionViewController.useLayoutToLayoutNavigationTransitions = YES;

    nextCollectionViewController.title = @"FullScreen";
    return nextCollectionViewController;

}
```

In **FullScreenCollectionViewController**, I register FullPhotoCell class

```
[self.collectionView registerClass:[FullPhotoCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:CELL_ID_FULL];
```

But sequence code never call

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    FullPhotoCell* cell = (FullPhotoCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CELL_ID_FULL forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSLog(@"Reuse FULL Cell");
    FICDPhoto *photo = [_photos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.imageView.image = [photo sourceImage];
    return cell;
}
```

New layout is apply, viewDidload of FullScreenCollectionViewController also call, but the log message "reuse CELL" tell that fullScreen CollectionView still use old PhotoCell class.

I still don't understand what's problem. Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "a bit" late but this might be useful for someone else. When you use `useLayoutToLayoutNavigationTransitions` the collection view from the view controller initiating the transition is actually reused. This collection view has a different data source and delegate and that's why `FullScreenCollectionViewController`'s `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is not being called. Take a look at this similar question:
[UICollectionView UseLayoutToLayoutNavigationTransitions with different datasources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21878687/uicollectionview-uselayouttolayoutnavigationtransitions-with-different-datasourc)