# UICollectionView UseLayoutToLayoutNavigationTransitions with different datasources

Tags: ios, ios7, xamarin, uicollectionview

I have two `UICollectionView` objects, that both have different source and delegate. I would like to achieve a "Photos app'esque" look with the transition, using UseLayoutToLayoutNavigationTransitions.

It doesn't work though. When I call the `UseLayoutToLayoutNavigationTransitions` it changes the layout, but not the content.

First picture is first collection view. A series of categories and the people contained in them.

Second picture is what I'd like the animation to end up in. A series of people within a certain category.

Last picture is what happens right now. Categories just get rearranged.

[image: First CollectionView][image: What I'd like the animation to end up with][image: What it looks like now.]

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at http://www.objc.io/issue-12/collectionview-animations.html in the

> Transitions Between UICollectionViewController Instances

section.

it basically shows you that you'll have to change the datasource and delegate manually by implementation of the navigation controller delegate methods:

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[FJDetailViewController class]]) {
        FJDetailViewController *dvc = (FJDetailViewController*)viewController;
        dvc.collectionView.dataSource = dvc;
        dvc.collectionView.delegate = dvc;
        [dvc.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:_selectedItem inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredVertically animated:NO];
    }
    else if (viewController == self){
        self.collectionView.dataSource = self;
        self.collectionView.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that during the transition iOS will change the datasource.  See my answer to this question [How to use useLayoutToLayoutNavigationTransitions in UICollectionView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20874955/how-to-use-uselayouttolayoutnavigationtransitions-in-uicollectionview/22469764#22469764)

You can use the same pattern described there:

- use `UseLayoutToLayoutNavigationTransitions` to get the layout changes
- observe when the transition is done
- set the datasource to the one you need at that point